# SQL Syntax error or access violation after placing an order?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, onepage-checkout

I am working in magento1.7.
When I placed an order in the last step of checkout process, then it gives me the following error instead of showing success page..

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

The full error log file is as follows..

```
a:5:{i:0;s:203:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1";i:1;s:5461:"#0 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `sales_f...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order), 'increment_id')
#8 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(512): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order), 'increment_id')
#9 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(500): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->loadByAttribute('increment_id', Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#10 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/design/frontend/tapestore/iphone/template/checkout/success.phtml(42): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->loadByIncrementId(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order))
#11 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/chroot/home/th...')
#12 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tapest...')
#13 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#19 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/design/frontend/tapestore/iphone/template/page/1column.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#20 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/chroot/home/th...')
#21 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/tapest...')
#22 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#26 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(244): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#27 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->successAction()
#28 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('success')
#29 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /chroot/home/project/Mystore.com/html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/checkout/onepage/success/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:23:"mystore_store_view";}
```

And in the browser console following error shows..

> "Network error : 503 service unavailable - http://Mystore.com/checkout/onepage/success"

Could anyone suggest where to start investigation for the above error ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11131/what-is-causing-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-when-try

Comment: Check your logs and update your question with a more specific error message.

Comment: You'll need to provide the erroneous query. Follow this question to enable SQL logging: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25113/how-to-log-all-magento-sql. Then, post the last query that tried to execute in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`. It should start with `SELECT sales_f...`.

Comment: @musicliftsme, I enable the query debug and came to that ,the erroneous query is same as the first line of the information that I have provided here. And the extra information is a "503 service unavailable is coming in the console of the browser"..

Answer (score 0):

It is the success.phtml that was creating problem, in my case.
The way I get the order_id was wrong.
I had written..

> $order_id = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());

When I change it to defalut one..like..

> $order_id = $this->getOrderId();

then it worked fine.
But I still can't figure out why is it happend ?